# Combo Charts (Bar+Line) in DC.js or D3.js

Tags: d3.js, charts, dc.js

I am trying to make a Combo chart (Bar and Line) using DC.js or D3.js. Basically it is of two series, first is a Quarter series and another is week series. Quarter series should have bar charts and week series should show in line chart. Please see the below screenshot.

[image: Composite chart]

Comment: Could you share your code? It looks like you are using an ordinal scale when you should be using a time scale.

Comment: Hi Gordon, yes I will be using the Ordinal scale as the x-axis is having string values. My main issue is, how can I append two different charts together. Bar chart for quarter and line chart for weekly. Two series which common y-axis. I searched online but did not find any example of this kind of charts (appending two charts).

Comment: You can do this with `d3` but you need to put a little effort in.  Take a shot at coding it yourself, when you get stuck come back with specific code/question...

Comment: @Mohammad did you find any solution ?